# Couchdb view filtering by date

Tags: view, couchdb, mapreduce

I have a simple document named Order structure with the fields id, name,
userId and timeScheduled.

What I would like to do is create a view where I can find the
document.id for those who's userId is some value and timeScheduledis
after a given date.

My view:

```
"by_users_after_time": {
      "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.userId && doc.timeScheduled) {
emit([doc.timeScheduled, doc.userId], doc._id); }}"
  }
```

If I do

```
localhost:5984/orders/_design/Order/_view/by_users_after_time?startKey="[2012-01-01T11:40:52.280Z,f98ba9a518650a6c15c566fc6f00c157]"
```

I get every result back. Is there a way to access key[1] to do an if
doc.userId == key[1] or something along those lines and simply emit on the
time?

This would be the SQL equivalent of

```
select id from Order where userId =
"f98ba9a518650a6c15c566fc6f00c157" and timeScheduled >
2012-01-01T11:40:52.280Z;
```

I did quite a few Google searches but I can't seem to find a good tutorial
on working with multiple keys. It's also possible that my approach is
entirely flawed so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer actually came from the couchdb mailing list:

Essentially, the Date.parse() doesn't like the +0000 on the timestamps. By
doing a substring and removing the +0000, everything worked.

For the record,

```
document.write(new Date("2012-02-13T16:18:19.565+0000")); //Outputs Invalid
Date
document.write(Date.parse("2012-02-13T16:18:19.565+0000")); //Outputs NaN
```

But if you remove the +0000, both lines of code work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to reverse the key, because username is known:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.userId && doc.timeScheduled) {
    emit([doc.userId, doc.timeScheduled], 1);
  }
}
```

Then query with:

```
?startkey=["f98ba9a518650a6c15c566fc6f00c157","2012-01-01T11:40:52.280Z"]
```

NOTES:

- the query parameter is `startkey`, not `startKey`;
- the value of `startkey` is an array, not a string. Then the double quotes go around the username and date values, not around the array.
- I  emit `1` as value, instead of `doc._id`, to save disk-space. Every row of the result has an `id` field with the `doc._id`, then there's no need to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

don't forget to set an endkey=["f98ba9a518650a6c15c566fc6f00c157",{}], otherwise you get the data of all users > "f98ba9a518650a6c15c566fc6f00c157"